# How to align navigationTitle with menu button (toolbarItem)?

Tags: swiftui, toolbar

I have a navigationView with a toolbarItem button to block/report users. But the navigationTitle is not aligned with the menu button...

is there a way to align them horizontally?

otherwise I'll be forced to ditch the toolbar and just use a HStack as header.

[image]

```
                NavigationView{
                    VStack {
                       ...bunch of code
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text(model.matches[index].name).font(.subheadline), displayMode: .large)
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            Menu(content: {
                                Text("Menu Item 1")
                                Text("Menu Item 2")
                                Text("Menu Item 3")
                            }, label: {Image(systemName: "ellipsis")})
                        }
                    }
                    //.ignoresSafeArea(.top)
                }
```

Comment: Yeah, just use a `HStack`. It's super hard to customize system ui like `NavigationView`.

Answer (score 1):

.navigationBarTitle(Text(model.matches[index].name).font(.subheadline), displayMode: **.inline**)

Comment: Precisely. Use displayMode: .inline. This should be the accepted answer